# Printing the output in a file instead of the stdout in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, stdout

I am writing a code, where I am generating some rules. Below are the last few lines of my code:

```
for _,i in enumerate(range(no_of_label+1)):
    
        if _ in temp_key:
        
            rule_pro.append(temp_lab[_])
            
        elif _ == no_of_label:
        
            rule_pro.append(class_)
            
        else:
        
            rule_pro.append("*")
            
    print(*rule_pro, sep = ",")
```

Now in between the code I am generating 3-4 outputs in the stdout as well. But I need to write this `rule_pro` into a file say, `Outputfile`. Whenever I am trying to copy this thing from stdout to that file, everything that is in stdout is getting copied but I only need to bring that `rule_pro` inside a file. How can I do that? Please help!

Edit_1 :

```
with open('Output_rule_c45_rise_format', 'w') as file_handler:

file_handler.write(str(rule_pro))
```

This is working but I am not getting my desired format, which I was getting in `stdout` using `print(*rule_pro, sep = ",")`.

The `stdout` output was like:

```
*,*,1,*,0
*,*,2,2,1
*,*,*,3,1
*,*,*,4,2
*,*,3,*,2
```

But modifying the code, in that outputfile I am getting like :

```
['*', '*', '1', '*', '0']['*', '*', '2', '2', '1']['*', '*', '*', '3', '1']['*', '*', '*', '4', '2']['*', '*', '3', '*', '2']
```

But I don't need these 3rd brackets and I need to print them in separate lines. What changes should I need to make?

Edit_2:

Now I am doing :

```
for rule in rule_pro:
            #rule_line = ','.join(map(str, rule))
            #rule_line = "\n".join(map(str, rule))
            rule_line = "\n".join(map(str, rule)) + '\n'
            file_handler.write(rule_line)
```

But this is giving the output as:

```
*
*
1
*
0
*
*
2
2
1
*
*
*
3
1
*
*
*
4
2
*
*
3
*
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Edit 1.

It seems that you are writing a string representation of a list into a file.
You should first try to create a string out of the list.

The code below should help you convert this. It iterates trough the list and obtaining every item. In this case it seems you have a list with lists and thus your item is a list. After this, a string is joined/created by using every item in rule (which is a list) and then saves it in a variable. The rule_line is a string and can be written to the file. A newline is added so it gets on the next line in the file.

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-list-to-string/)

```py
with open('Output_rule_c45_rise_format', 'w') as file_handler:
    for rule in rule_pro: 
        rule_line = ','.join(map(str, rule)) + '\n'
        file_handler.write(rule_line)
```

This should work assuming that rule_pro is a list of lists.

After Edit 2.

The IndentationError is a problem with the consistency of your spaces and/or tabs. Try to use only tabs **or** only 4 spaces in your code. Do not mix tabs and spaces in the indentation.

If rule_pro is a list with lists it would look like this.

```py
rule_pro = [['*', '*', '1', '*', '0'],
            ['*', '*', '2', '2', '1'],
            ['*', '*', '*', '3', '1'],
            ['*', '*', '*', '4', '2'],
            ['*', '*', '3', '*', '2']]
```

You can check if your line is correct by trying the following:

```py
for rule in rule_pro:
    rule_line = ','.join(map(str, rule)) + '\n'
    print(rule_line)
```

Please check if your rule_pro list is similar to the rule_pro I have in mind.

Comment: It is showing `rule_line = ','.join(map(str, rule)) + '\n'
                                              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
`

Comment: I declared rule_pro as : `rule_pro = []`

Comment: Can you please check my Edit_2?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Could you show me the contents of your rule_pro variable? print(rule_pro)

Comment: Yes now it is working absolutely fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Nice! Good to hear! You're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

**check docs:**
Python File Handling:https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp

Python File Open:https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

Python File Write:https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Python File Delete:https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_remove.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).